# Copy database fails with SQL Agent not started error, but it is running

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm trying to copy a database to another server. I've successfully done this with these two servers several times, the last time was just a few days ago. However, now when I try to execute it, I get an error:

```
TITLE: Copy Database Wizard
------------------------------

Start failed for Job 'CDW_xxxx_SGSTG51DBA01_13_2'. 

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch
(Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------

SQLServerAgent is not currently running so it cannot be notified of this action. 
(Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 22022)
```

Base on this information, I immediately checked that SQL Agent was running. It wasn't, so I started it. I ran it again, but got the same error. I then double checked that the login information provided for both the source and destination servers was correct. It was.

So I'm now getting this error with verified connection information and SQL agent **is** running. What else could be causing this problem? Does the account running SQL agent need access to both servers?

Comment: Did you check SQL Server Agent on *both* machines? Sounds like you only checked one (and perhaps not the right one). You could also just consider performing a backup and restore, which doesn't require the wizard, SSIS, or SQL Server Agent.

Comment: You're a genius!  I didn't understand that SQL Agent had to be running on BOTH servers. And it wasn't running on the second. I works now.

Comment: Also, I did try a backup and restore. Backed up on the source, copied to a shared folder on target (i.e. used a shared folder to move the .bak files). But when I tried to do the restore on the target, it didn't show the files, even when I picked the 'All Files' option. No idea what that was about.

Comment: Well, the SQL Server service account probably didn't have access to the shared folder (even if *you* do). Next time try copying the .bak file to the local server.

Comment: What is the suggested way to mark this as answered. Aaron initial comment lead to the solution (SQL Agent wasn't started on the target server)?